# paperclip inputs and previews for uploaded images in edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using paperclip and rails 4 and multiple image uploading works correctly. However I would like to configure it to allow uploading of a maximum of 3 images and **only show inputs and previews for uploaded images.**

If I upload an image out of the 3 possible images.. and then go to the edit action.. it still shows 3 upload input elements instead of 2. And all of them say "no file chosen" which is not good for the user. The user might replace the image while thinking they are adding a new one.

How can I modify my edit action or my form so that for **filled assets**, the `choose file` input actually shows the uploaded file name instead of `No file chosen` when an image has previously been uploaded or not show the input element at all?

My form fields:

```
   <%= f.fields_for :assets do |builder| %>
    <% unless builder.object.new_record? %>
         <p>Images</p>
       <%=link_to image_tag(builder.object.attachment.url(:thumb)), builder.object.attachment.url(:original) %>
      Delete: <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

My controller actions:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    3.times { @post.assets.build }
...
    end
  end


  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])  
    if @post.assets.count < 3
      3.times { @post.assets.build }
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :post
 #attr_accessible :attachment
 has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "600x600>", :small => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
 :default_url => "no_image_fr_:style.png"
 validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
end
```

**Attributes for Asset table**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base {
                         :id => :integer,
                 :post_id => :integer,
                 :created_at => :datetime,
                 :updated_at => :datetime,
       :attachment_file_name => :string,
    :attachment_content_type => :string,
       :attachment_file_size => :integer,
      :attachment_updated_at => :datetime
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

So it looks the `(3 - @assets.count).times { @assets.build }`does build the correct number of assets but it still displays 3 input elements no matter what.

What causes

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.input :attachment, as: :file, :label => "Image:", wrapper: :horizontal_file_input  %>
<% end %>
```

to always show 3 inputs even though `assets.count` = 1 ??

Comment: Show me your model related to `assets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually finally figured out a nice way to do this

to display only the remaining field fields I had to check if it was still a  new record... even though assets.count was correct, the number of fields displayed was incorrect. This verification helped.

```
 <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
```

to display only the "filled" assets, I had to check if it's not a new record!

```
<% @post.assets.each do |ast| %>

  <% if !ast.new_record? %> 

   <%=link_to image_tag(ast.attachment.url(:thumb)), ast.attachment.url(:medium), :popup=>['original_image', 'height=700,width=900'] %>  <%= check_box_tag :_destroy %>   delete  </br></br>
   <%end%>

<% end %>
```

Now in the edit action it only shows the remaining fields... and when an asset is already filled, it shows a little preview with a deletion checkbox!

Still curious why the file fields were always showing 3 even though post.assets.count was correct.

I'm awarding the bounty to Raj who made considerable effort in trying to find a solution.

Comment: nice trick.. thanks for bounty.. I'll also try to figure out that why `assets.count` was given wrong result..

Answer (score 4):

Reject your unused `file_fields`:

```
# model
has_attached_file :attachment,
                     :styles => {
                       :medium => "600x600>",
                       :small => "200x200>",
                       :thumb => "100x100>" },
                     :default_url => "no_image_fr_:style.png",
                     :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['attachment'].nil? }
```

Update your `edit` action, so that it shows only remaining number of file fields

```
# controller
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])  
  @assets = @post.assets
  (3 - @assets.count).times { @assets.build }
end
```

Show already uploaded images and required `file_fields`.

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.file_field :attachment %>
<% end %>

<p>Images</p>
<% @assets.each do |a| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(a.attachment.url(:thumb)), a.attachment.url(:original) %>
  Delete: <%= check_box_tag :_destroy %>
<% end %>
```

Test it after cleaning up your assets table.

Comment: answer makes a lot of sense just getting this undefined method `check_box' for #<Asset:0x007faa9c2a4df8> to work before testing it (replaced builder with a)

Comment: even after correcting the typo I still get undefined method `check_box' for #<Asset:0x007faa9c2a4df8>

Comment: Delete: <%= check_box_tag :_destroy %>

Comment: ok now I see my upload buttons .. when I upload an image it actually uploads the default image..no_image_fr_:style.png and in the edit action it still shows "no file chosen"

Comment: added attributes to question description

Comment: update `file_field` as `<%= builder.file_field :attachment %>`

Comment: cool now images upload but still "no file chosen" This is how it looks like in the edit action after 1 image is uploaded "the logo image" http://imgdump.nl/hosted/b8e573f1093b0f40e0fb0393a494fe38.png

Comment: `file_fields` are getting shown because you have not used all file fields yet

Comment: yes.. but if a file_field is used I want it to be shown not say "No file chosen" .. It works in the new action (example http://imgdump.nl/hosted/23a5e903d55159e559f50ee748705541.png)  . I want the same thing in the edit action.

Comment: Its seems wrong approach, if you will have this thing, it will save your image again. However, as per my answer, you will be able to see already uploaded images, and remaining `file_fields`

Comment: hi sorry maybe I wasn't clear. but as per your answer I see already uploaded images but ALL file_fields.. NOT remaining file_fields. For example if I upload only one image. In the edit action I see 3 file fields and not 2 (the remaining ones)

Comment: Oh..! that should work.. anyways try `(3 - @post.assets.count).times { @post.assets.build }` instead of `(3 - @assets.count).times { @assets.build }`

Comment: mmm there must something else at play.. I uploaded two images, i can see the thumbnails, but I still have 3 file_fields all saying "no file chosen" see here http://imgdump.nl/hosted/6b3bbdd5d259fe72ec01683969118a03.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58980/discussion-between-raj-and-ayrad).

Answer (score 1):

You might try only building new assets for the number of images that have not been created. Your edit action would look like this:

```
def edit
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   (3 - @post.assets.count).times do
     @post.assets.build
   end
end
```

also you'll want to keep in mind that if you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Post` model you might need to add the `update_only: true`

hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion1 However when I create a post with an image then go to edit, the file browse button still shows "No file chosen". When I choose a file, it replaces the existing one. I would like it to show that there is already a file there instead of "No file Chosen". Also even though there is one image already there, 3 file inputs are still shown instead of 2. It doesn't take into account the first picture.

Comment: I might add I'm using gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"