# How can I update the last record instead of create a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload images.
What I want is, when the file exists, instead of this create a new record, update the last one with the name of file.
In paperclip, the file was named `path`.

I'm trying this:

```
 def create
  if(params[:path])
   @photo = current_user.photos.update_attribute(:path, params[:path]).last
  else
   @photo = current_user.photos.new(photo_params)
  end
end
```

My file input name is `photo[path]`

I want to add just `path` value to an already existing row:
[image]

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25184341/1047207

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Rails magic here, specifically the `find_or_create_by` and its variants. For example, if you do this:

```
@photo = current_user.photos.find_or_create_by_path(params[:path])
```

It will first look for an entry with that path, and create a new one if it can't find it. Note that you can also use Ruby's [try method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) instead of the `if params[:path]` block.

Please see [the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) for more info on `find_or_create_by`.